# How to merge two files of different number of lines using blank line condition?

Tags: awk, paste

I have two files, one have diffrent section separted by blank line as follows

```
a11 a12 a13
b11 b12 b13
c11 c12 c13

a21 a22 a23
b21 b22 b23
c21 c22 c23
d21 d22 d23

a31 a32 a33
b31 b32 b33
```

the second file has number of lines equal to the number of sections in the 1st file

```
x1 X2
y1 y2 
z1 z2
```

the out required output

```
a11 a12 a13 x1 x2
b11 b12 b13
c11 c12 c13

a21 a22 a23 y1 y2
b21 b22 b23
c21 c22 c23
d21 d22 d23

a31 a32 a33 z1 z2
b31 b32 b33
```

I tried with `paste file1 file2` but it does not give the desired output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[NR]=$0; next} {print $0 (pNF ? "" : OFS a[++c]); pNF=NF}' file2 file1
a11 a12 a13 x1 X2
b11 b12 b13
c11 c12 c13

a21 a22 a23 y1 y2
b21 b22 b23
c21 c22 c23
d21 d22 d23

a31 a32 a33 z1 z2
b31 b32 b33
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the awk's range operator:

```
$ awk '
  !B {a[NR]=$0;next}
  NF,!NF {
    if (!f++) $(NF+1) = a[++i]
    f = NF
  };1
' ./file2 B=1 ./file1
```

Using the GNU awk utility in  paragraph mode:

```
$ awk '
    BEGIN {
      factory_setting = RS
      RS = ""
      paragrph_mode = RS
      OFS = FS = "\n"
      ORS = "\n\n"
      f2 = ARGV[2]
      ARGV[2] = ""
    }
    {
      RS = factory_setting
        if (getline t < f2 > 0) $1=$1" "t 
      RS = paragrph_mode
    }1
'  ./file1 ./file2
a11 a12 a13 x1 x2
b11 b12 b13
c11 c12 c13

a21 a22 a23 x2 y2
b21 b22 b23
c21 c22 c23
d21 d22 d23

a31 a32 a33 x3 y3
b31 b32 b33

$
```